# Edit Text value is not updated

Tags: android

In my application I entered value into editText field into 2 ways one is Depending on the spinner selection value will be changed and other way is through softkeyboard. Now problem is when i  entered value into the edittext through key board and orientation is changed at that time edittext field contain the value depending on the spinner.but i want whatevet i enter value into the edittext filed that value is appeared in thta edit text field if the orientation is changed.For this what can i do ,Give me some suggestions.Thanks in  advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity is restarted when the device changes orientation so have a look at onSavedInstanceState in the activity documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html